# How to delete a special row

Tags: vba, excel

In sheet1 I have one cell A3 (52):

[image: Screenshot 1]

In the sheet 2, I want to delete the row where there is the number of A3 of the sheet 1. This number can only be in the first column.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub delete_ligne()

Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To 6600

    If (Cells(i,1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Modification").Range("B7").Value)

    Then
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    i = i - 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any solution?

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" mean?

Comment: You are comparing the value in cell B7 of the sheet "Modification" to the cells you are looping through, not cell A3 in "Sheet 2" as in your description of the problem. Furthermore I would expect that not qualifying what sheet the cells you loop through are in could create problems, if you are not 100% certain that you'll have the spreadsheet in need of modification as your active one at any timethe macro may be called. Furthermore, as Robert Harvey mentions, just saying that your code doesn't work isn't very helpful in tracking down the problem.

Comment: Also, you're deleting rows by moving from the top to the bottom. When you successfully delete row 10 (for example), row 11 will move up one row, so when your loop increments to check row 11, you'll be checking what was row 12 before the deletion, thus never looking at row 11. Change your loop to read `For i = 6600 to 1 Step -1` for a successful row deletion routine.

Comment: @FreeMan there is `i = i - 1` after deletion

Comment: Ah, @user3964075, valid point, I missed seeing that. That will work, though the 'bottom up' method is usually preferred for deletion loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what "It doesn't work" means, but this might help:

```
Sub delete_ligne()
Dim rng as Range
Dim WB as Workbook
Dim i As Integer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set WB = 'define your workbook here
  Set rng = WB.Sheet(2).Range("B:B").Find (What:=WB.Sheet(1).Range("A3"), _
          LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
  While not Rng is Nothing
    rng.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Set rng = WB.Sheet(2).Range("B:B").Find (What:=WB.Sheet(1).Range("A3"), _
              LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
  Wend

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Adjust to define `WB`, `Sheet(2)`, and `Sheet(1)` as necessary to point to the correct locations.

The `.Find` will be substantially faster than looping 6600 rows and doesn't care what order it finds/deletes the rows.

You can add an outer loop if there are more cells to be checked that `"A3"`

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer.What do you means by define your workbook here??Sorry))

Comment: For example: `Set WB = ActiveWorkbook`. By assigning the workbook to a variable it protects your loop against an accidental change of the active workbook suddenly deleting code from the wrong place.

Comment: No problem. Please be sure to click the checkmark on whichever answer helped you the most. Having "answered" questions helps the whole community.

Comment: Dear,Sorry but how can I define th WB ?? Sorry butI thought It was working one time but not anymore..((((

Comment: `Set WB = ThisWorkbook` or `Set WB = ActiveWorkbook` or `Set WB = Workbooks("MyWorkbookName")`

Comment: Thanks I had tried but still doesn't work(((

Comment: I would suggest updating the original post with with an edit showing what you currently have, or, potentially, starting a whole new question. It's hard to diagnose "it still doesn't work" without being able to see exactly what you've done, and some indication of where "it doesn't work", and what sort of error message(s) you're receiving.

Comment: Also, comment out the `Application.screenupdating=false`. You'll want that when everything is working OK, but until then, it just makes life difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly ;

```
Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wsThis As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim tmp As Integer

Sub delete_ligne()
    Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsThis = wbThis.Sheets(1)
    Set wsTarget = wbThis.Sheets(2)



    For i=1 To 100      
        wsThis.Activate
        tmp = wsThis.Cells(3, i).Value
        For j=3 To 100
            wsTarget.Activate
            If Cells(j,1).Value = tmp Then
                Cells(j,1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

**First Loop (i) :** 
First For Loop is looping through the cells of the Sheet 1. It starts from A3 and goes until A100. You can tweak the values in the code.

**Second Loop (j) :** 
Second For Loop is looping through the cells of the Sheet 2 for each element of the First Loop. If any value is it deletes the row entirely.

Comment: Dear,ManyThanks!! But still have a problem :  tmp = wsThis.Cells(3, i).Value----> Error written : Incompatible Type

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work... 
Just double check which cell actually has your value as your code and question don't agree.

```
Sub delete_ligne()
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 6600 To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i,1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Modification").Range("A3").Value Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer)) the code delete the row over A3 but I need to delete an other row in other sheet, can be A5, A16.....

Comment: That was not the question you asked... If you have further values then you should make this clear in your question